# Allow a user to create files in another users directory

Tags: permissions, group, chmod

I have a website which is owned by user apache and group apache and I want to allow another user to be able to work within a folder on the website - I need them to be able to edit and create new files within that folder.

I added a user and assigned them a password and then changed their home directory to the folder I want to give them access to.

```
/etc/passwd
peter:x:1016:1017::/home/application/public_html/documents:/bin/bash
```

Then I added them to the apache group:

```
[root@app01 documents]# groups peter
peter : peter apache
```

And then ensured that the folder in which I want them to work is (a) owned by apache and (b) allows the group to read and write. (I also tried 777 as a test but still didn't work)

```
drwxrwxr-x+  6 apache apache     4096 Nov 16 09:03 documents
```

Then I log in as the user and try to create a file within the folder but I get the below:

```
-bash-4.2$ touch 123.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘123.txt’: Permission denied

[root@app01]# getfacl documents
# file: documents
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:apache:rw-
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:apache:rw-
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

I can edit files in the directory and save them with no issues but not create new files or folders - what else do I need to do to allow this to work?

Comment: '+' at the end of the permissions means the directory has an Access Control List (ACL); see http://serverfault.com/questions/227852/what-does-a-mean-at-the-end-of-the-permissions-from-ls-l . Look at `getfacl` if Linux, or `ls -e` if MacOSX.

Comment: Ah interesting, I will get the output and see what it shows

Answer (score 2):

typically you'll want to create shared / co-op space outside user homes, /var/www/website1/public_html as a suggestion.

create a group called website1 and a user website1, also create a group website1-admin.

you can then set the dirs to be 775.

/var/www/website1 can be website1:website1-admin
/var/www/website1/public_html can be website1:website1

then add all users who need write access to website1 group, also add apache to this group.

the admins can be put in group website1-admin, which will allow then access to edit files outside the public_html.

this allows you to keep the user's home /home/wesbite1 locked down to 700.